# _kbhit() not integer when trying to sleep thread

Tags: c++, c++20, conio

i'm trying to make a stopwatch pause by making the thread sleep until a key is pressed, but _kbhit() will not return an integer?

the error is displayed in the image below:
[image]

i tried to a quick search but wasn't able to find a solution to my problem

Comment: neither `conio.h` nor `_kbhit` are in the C++ standard. Just avoid them

Comment: @phuclv what's an alternative for getting unbuffered key input then?

Comment: [`std::this_thread::sleep_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) does not take an `int` as its argument. It takes an `std::chrono::time_point`.

Comment: @heapunderrun the error states that the required argument type is an integer, and the ms docs say that it returns a non-zero value (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit?view=msvc-170)

Comment: No, it states that the argument you have provided is `int`, but there is no overload taking such type (`int`).

Comment: I can see how you read the message that way. It's probably only years of experience that have us reading the message the "right" way. Not very intuitive.